# How to create a Scheduled Task via Invoke-command when Blanks in a Path are involved?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Trying to create a Scheduled Task where a Powershell copy-item task is started. (To mitigate the Double Hop Issue") Having the copy-item command in a *.ps1 File and just call this is not a prefered way for me as i plan to build the Path Names on the fly once this example is working.

Following is working as expected:

```
Invoke-Command -session $mysession -ScriptBlock { schtasks /create /RU myuser /RP mypasswd  /TN "Temp Task Copy-Item" /TR "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command  copy-item -path \\192.168.1.1\share\Folder -Destination C:\Temp" /SC ONCE /ST 22:35}
```

But what is the magic syntax  when i want to copy to a Path with blanks  **C:\Program Files (x86)\Temp**  instead of the **C:\Temp**
Think i've tried all ways of Backticks combination and had no luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the single quote around the path with spaces and it will work.

```
Invoke-Command -session $mysession -ScriptBlock { schtasks /create /RU myuser /RP mypasswd  /TN "Temp Task Copy-Item" /TR "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command  copy-item -path \\192.168.1.1\share\Folder -Destination 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Temp'" /SC ONCE /ST 22:35}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works kind of..
First Problem will be that i couldn't use Variables within the single qoutes. But the bigger Problem is that the single qoutes are "translated" to double qutes in the Task Scheduler. And this seems to cause a Problem as well. I will do some more investigation on this..

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for my Problem: i skip using Copy-Item and use plain CMD for the copy:

```
#Set Source & Dest
$source = "\\192.168.1.1\share\Folder\*"
$dest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Temp"

#Build command (Note: Single Quotes +"'" will appear in Schedueld Task as Double Quotes
$copycmd = "schtasks /create /RU myuser/RP mypasswd  /TN `"Temp Task Copy-Item`" /SC ONCE /ST 22:35 /TR `"cmd /c copy "+"'"+"$source"+"'"+" "+"'"+"$dest"+"'"+" "
#Run Command
Invoke-Command -session $mysession -ScriptBlock { cmd /c  "$args"} -ArgumentList $copycmd
```